# how to get some unique columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns with same name and values in excel, how to keep unique column in pandas

I am doing below:

```python
## Update4: adding empty columns###
#### combined data many rows with single rows ###
### rename the columns and insert the empty columns##
### Lat Long change to 7 decimal place###

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import os

def process_excel():
    global df_2g_f
    global df_3g_f
    try:
        # Browse for the input Excel file
        input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])
        if not input_file_path:
            return

        # Load the input Excel file
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(input_file_path)
        output_folder = "C:/Verizon"
        current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        output_filename = f"Single_row_Data_{current_datetime}.xlsx"
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_filename)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path)

        # Process the "2G Datafill" tab
        if "2G Datafill" in excel_file.sheet_names:
            df_2g = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="2G Datafill")
            columns_to_drop = ["CellName","Tech", "Cell ID", "Site Name", "longitude", "latitude", "LAC", "NCC", "BCC",
                               "BCCHNO", "DCHNO", "bsPwrBDec", "Band", "channelGroup", "LCR", "g31TgId",
                               "HSN", "MAIO", "ParentNode", "gsmSectorId"]
            df_2g.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
            df_2g.rename(columns={"configuredMaxTxPower": "2G_configuredMaxTxPower"}, inplace=True)
            df_2g_f = df_2g

            # Merge with the "3G Datafill" tab based on "Nominal" values
        if "3G Datafill" in excel_file.sheet_names:
            df_3g = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="3G Datafill")
            columns_to_drop = ["Tech", "Cell ID", "Site Name", "RAC", "LAC", "SAC", "primScramCode", "uarfcnDL",
                               "uarfcnUL", "cpichPower", "maxTxPower", "LCR", "URA", "ParentNode"]
            df_3g.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
            df_3g.rename(columns={"configuredMaxTxPower": "3G_configuredMaxTxPower"}, inplace=True)
            df_3g_f = df_3g
                # Merge the data frames based on "Nominal" values

                #df_combined = df_combined.rename(columns={'Nominal': 'Name'})

        frames = [df_2g_f, df_3g_f]
        df_combined = pd.concat(frames)
        df_combined['Nominal'] = df_combined['Nominal'] + '_BB2'
        out = (df_combined
                   .replace('', np.nan).set_index('Nominal').stack().to_frame(name='value')
                  .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount())
                   .set_index('n', append=True)
                   ['value']
                   .unstack(level=[-1, -2]).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
                   .droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
                )
        out = out.rename(columns={'Nominal': 'Name'})
        out.insert(1, 'Node Type', 'Baseband')
        out.insert(2, 'Sw Release', '22.Q2')
        out.insert(3, 'Parent Rnc', '')
        out.insert(4, 'Parent Bsc', '')
        out.insert(5, 'Parent Baseband', '')
        out.insert(6, 'Connected Profile', '')
        out.insert(7, '#Template', '')
        out.insert(8, 'networkManagedElementId', '')
        out .rename(columns = {'2G DefaultRouter': 'address_2G_Default', '2G IP Address': 'address_2G_IP','3G DefaultRouter':'address_3G_Default' , '3G IP Address': 'address_3G_IP', 'BSC Broker IP': 'bscBrokerIpAddress', 'CellName': 'nodeBLocalCellId'}, inplace = True)
        default_value = 0
        out['latitude'] = (out['latitude'].fillna(default_value) * 10**5).astype(int)
        out['longitude'] = (out['longitude'].fillna(default_value) * 10**6).astype(int)


        column_name = "2G_configuredMaxTxPower"
        column_counts = out.columns.astype(str).value_counts()

        print("column_counts are follow:", column_counts)
        if column_name in column_counts and column_counts[column_name] > 1:
            duplicate_columns = out.columns[out.columns.isin([column_name])].tolist()
            print("Duplicate columns are:", duplicate_columns)
            for duplicate_column in duplicate_columns[1:]:
                out = out.drop(columns=duplicate_column)

        out.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Combined Data", index=False)

        writer.save()
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Data processing completed.")

    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


# Create the Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Excel Data Processor")
window.geometry("300x150")

# Create the "Process" button
btn_process = tk.Button(window, text="Process Excel", command=process_excel)
btn_process.pack(pady=10)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

but getting `error :2G_configuredMaxTxPower not found in axis`, when I am dropping the all columns it is getting dropped but when I am dropping number of desired duplicate columns it is not getting deleted

input:

```
2G_configuredMaxTxPower| 2G_configuredMaxTxPower|2G_configuredMaxTxPower|
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
 15000                  | 15000                  | 15000                 |
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
  15000                 | 15000                  | 15000                 |
------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

desire output:

```
-------------------------+
 2G_configuredMaxTxPower |
-------------------------+
 15000                   |
-------------------------+
```

my output df:
[image]

`column_counts` are follow:

```
nodeBLocalCellId           6
address_3G_Default         6
rbsid                      6
fingerprint                6
iubId                      6
latitude                   6
address_3G_IP              6
longitude                  6
3G_configuredMaxTxPower    6
address_2G_Default         3
gsmSectorName              3
address_2G_IP              3
2G_configuredMaxTxPower    3
bscBrokerIpAddress         3
Sw Release                 1
Node Type                  1
Parent Bsc                 1
Connected Profile          1
Name                       1
#Template                  1
Parent Rnc                 1
Parent Baseband            1
networkManagedElementId    1
dtype: int64
```

Duplicate columns are:

```
['2G_configuredMaxTxPower', '2G_configuredMaxTxPower', '2G_configuredMaxTxPower']
```

by applying this I am getting error "2G_configuredMaxTxPower" not find in axis

Comment: _...by applying this I am getting error "2G_configuredMaxTxPower" not find in axis..._ 
What exactly are you _applying_?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the columns by location.
For example - if your columns are in positions 2, 3 & 4:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: "newcol_2", df.columns[3]: "newcol_3", df.columns[4]: "newcol_4"}, inplace = True)
```

Is this what you wanted?